# Is it possible to have platform attributes?

Tags: linux-device-driver

Rather than having device driver attributes - which, after a short survey of the code, seems to always reference global variable in the driver module - is it possible to have the `show(struct kobject *, struct kobj_attribute *, char *buf)` and `store(struct kobject *, struct kobj_attribute *, const char *buf, size_t count)` methods operate on, say, instance data referenced by `void *platform_get_drvdata(const struct platform_device *)`?

***Is there any association between the parameters given to the `show()` and `store()` functions and, say `(struct device *)x->kobj`?***

I can create separate SYSFS entries each time my `probe()` function is called, and it would be nice (in my case) to have attributes that correspond to that SYSFS entry and the probe instance, rather than to the driver globally.

---

**EDIT**

This is what I came up with.  Rather than using the handy 'ATTRIBUTE_GROUPS' macro (and others) which declare static global variables, I allocated everything:

```
struct am_attributes {
    void * var;
    struct kobj_attribute attr;
}

static const struct attribute_group **am_attribute_groups(struct am_instance *instance, struct device *dev)
{
    struct am_attribute *const am_ms_delay_attr = devm_kzalloc(dev, sizeof(struct am_attribute), GFP_KERNEL);
    struct am_attribute *const am_enable_attr = devm_kzalloc(dev, sizeof(struct am_attribute), GFP_KERNEL);
    struct attribute **const am_attrs = devm_kzalloc(dev, 3 * sizeof(struct attribute *), GFP_KERNEL);
    struct attribute_group *const am_group = devm_kzalloc(dev, sizeof(struct attribute_group), GFP_KERNEL);
    struct attribute_group **const am_groups = devm_kzalloc(dev, 2 * sizeof(struct attribute_group *), GFP_KERNEL);

    if (am_ms_delay_attr && am_enable_attr && am_attrs && am_group && am_groups)
    {
        struct kobj_attribute ms_pause = __ATTR_RW(autowrap_ms_pause);
        struct kobj_attribute enable = __ATTR_RW(autowrap_enable);

        /* Create the attributes for this probe instance. */
        am_ms_delay_attr->var = &instance->autowrap_ms_delay;
        am_ms_delay_attr->attr = ms_pause;

        am_enable_attr->var = &instance->autowrap_enable;
        am_enable_attr->attr = enable;

        am_attrs[0] = &am_ms_delay_attr->attr.attr;
        am_attrs[1] = &am_enable_attr->attr.attr;
        am_attrs[2] = NULL;

        am_group->attrs = am_attrs;

        am_groups[0] = am_group;
        am_groups[1] = NULL;

        return (const struct attribute_group **)am_groups;
    }
    else
    {
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

and in my probe function I'm doing:

```
...

instance->class->dev_groups = am_attribute_groups(instance, dev);

if (instance->class->dev_groups == NULL)
{
    pr_warn("Couldn't allocate SYSFS attributes.");
    ...
```

Finally, in the `show()` and `store()` functions I use the `container_of` macro to "rewind" the `attr` parameter to get `struct am_attribute` pointer and the `void * var;` pointer. (which I then cast):

```
#define to_am_attribute(x) container_of(x, struct am_attribute, attr)

static ssize_t autowrap_ms_pause_show(struct kobject *kobj,
                                    struct kobj_attribute *attr,
                                    char *buf)
{
    struct am_attribute *am_attr = to_am_attribute(attr);
    (void)kobj;

    return sprintf(buf, "%d\n", *(int *)(am_attr->var));
}
```

The question now is: ***What sort of trouble am I asking for by doing this?*** (or "is this reasonable?")

Comment: I recommend to read the existing driver code and see how to do it better.

Comment: @0andriy:"How to do it better"  There's a lot of driver code; Perhaps you can comment on a pitfall here, or is there driver code top of mind that you'd recommend I'd look at?

Comment: Any recent enough driver with attributes that is enumerated on the platform bus.

Comment: @0andriy I know you're trying to be helpful, but that narrows it down to 80,000 lines of code.  I was hoping for something more substantive than "see how to do it better".

Comment: @0andriy What I've done doesn't seem far off what you suggested I look at ( [mlxreg_io_attr_init()](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.1/source/drivers/platform/mellanox/mlxreg-io.c#L151), but I'd super appreciate, specific, criticism if you're willing to oblige.