# Is there a way to associate a 'struct file' structure with 'struct platform_device'?

Tags: linux-device-driver

I'm writing a kernel module that has private attributes for each probed instance.  When performing different file operations, is it possible to access that private data?

The private data I'm referring to is stored using:

```
void platform_set_drvdata(struct platform_device *, void *);
```

and would like to be able to access that data from, say, a read file operation:

```
static ssize_t read(struct file *, char __user *, size_t , loff_t *);
```

I feel as though I've asked this before, but can't find the question: ***Is there a way to map a `struct file` object to a `struct platform_device` object (preferably without resorting to global variables)?***

---

**EDIT**

I looked through the `drivers/platform` directory of the kernel for an example of code that had `struct file_operations` object that had members using per-probed instance data.  The code I found seemed rather circular.

As of writing this, my platform instance data object now contains a `struct file_operations fops` member, which, when the `open()` is called I use the `container_of()` macro to get my instance data.

In the `probe()` function, I do:

```
static int am_probe(struct platform_device *pdev) {
    struct am_instance * instance = devm_kzalloc(dev, sizeof(struct am_instance), GFP_KERNEL);
    ...
    /* am_fops is in .rodata (and not a pointer) */
    instance->fops = am_fops;  
    rv = register_chrdev(0,  instance->device_name, &instance->fops);
    ...
    platform_set_drvdata(pdev, instance);
    ...
```

Then, in the `open()` method I do this:

```
static int am_open(struct inode *inode, struct file *file) {
    file->private_data = container_of(file->f_op, struct am_instance, fops);
    return 0;
}
```

The above works, in that from the `read()` function, I can access the instance data by examining the `file->private_data` field with an appropriate cast.

Comment: Yes, it’s possible. Show the code which you use to create those attributes.

Comment: @0andriy You'd commented on another post of mine where I show the code that creates those attributes: https://stackoverflow.com/q/71877576/32836

Comment: The way you have done it assigns each instance its own dynamically allocated major device number each with 256 minor device numbers. That is unconventional. Usually, the `register_chrdev` call is done during driver initialization and the device probe allocates a minor device number and associates it with the private data. You can use the `<linux/idr.h>` functions to map IDs to private data pointers for each instance. In the `open` handler, `inode->i_rdev` is the full device number being opened, `imajor(inode)` is the major device number and `iminor(inode)` is the minor device number.

Comment: @IanAbbott If that were an answer to this question (instead of a comment), I would accept it and upvote.  
Thank you.